# How to run django-apscheduler within a docker container that runs django via gunicorn

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, apscheduler

Is it possible to run django-apscheduler inside a docker container that runs django via gunicorn? Currently I have the problem that the custom manage.py command inside my entrypoint script runs forever and therefore gunicorn is never being executed.

My entrypoint script:

```
#!/bin/sh
python manage.py runapscheduler --settings=core.settings_dev_docker
```

My runapscheduler.py

```
# runapscheduler.py
import logging

from django.conf import settings

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django_apscheduler.jobstores import DjangoJobStore
from django_apscheduler.models import DjangoJobExecution
from django_apscheduler import util

from backend.scheduler.scheduler import scheduler

logger = logging.getLogger("backend")


def my_job():
    logger.error("Hello World!")
    # Your job processing logic here...
    pass


# The `close_old_connections` decorator ensures that database connections, that have become
# unusable or are obsolete, are closed before and after your job has run. You should use it
# to wrap any jobs that you schedule that access the Django database in any way.
@util.close_old_connections
# TODO: Change max_age to keep old jobs longer
def delete_old_job_executions(max_age=604_800):
    """
    This job deletes APScheduler job execution entries older than `max_age` from the database.
    It helps to prevent the database from filling up with old historical records that are no
    longer useful.

    :param max_age: The maximum length of time to retain historical job execution records.
                    Defaults to 7 days.
    """
    DjangoJobExecution.objects.delete_old_job_executions(max_age)


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Runs APScheduler."

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # scheduler = BlockingScheduler(timezone=settings.TIME_ZONE)
        # scheduler.add_jobstore(DjangoJobStore(), "default")

        scheduler.add_job(
            my_job,
            trigger=CronTrigger(minute="*/1"),  # Every 10 seconds
            id="my_job",  # The `id` assigned to each job MUST be unique
            max_instances=1,
            replace_existing=True,
        )
        logger.error("Added job 'my_job'.")

        scheduler.add_job(
            delete_old_job_executions,
            trigger=CronTrigger(
                day_of_week="mon", hour="00", minute="00"
            ),  # Midnight on Monday, before start of the next work week.
            id="delete_old_job_executions",
            max_instances=1,
            replace_existing=True,
        )
        logger.error(
            "Added weekly job: 'delete_old_job_executions'."
        )

        try:
            logger.error("Starting scheduler...")
            scheduler.start()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            logger.error("Stopping scheduler...")
            scheduler.shutdown()
            logger.error("Scheduler shut down successfully!")
```

The command in my docker container is the following:

```
command: gunicorn core.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

How do I properly run runapscheduler, so that gunicorn is also running? Do I have to create a separate process for runapscheduler?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and got it to work. I use `docker-compose` to start the process, but that is not relevant:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    container_name: django
    build: .
    command: >
      bash -c "pipenv run python manage.py makemigrations
      && pipenv run python manage.py migrate
      & wait

      pipenv run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
      & pipenv run python manage.py startscheduler"

    volumes:
      - ./xy:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
        - HOST=db
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

The important part is where we supply the `command`:

- if you use `&&` to chain the commands my second to last command won't exit and thus the next one won't launch
- if you use `&` to chain them, the two will run in parallel

I use the `wait` to wait for the first block to run before I launch the scheduler and app Gunicorn server together.

Extra tip: If you have logging configured in your `settings.py` (not relying on `print`) you can output the management command's logs into the `runserver`'s log stream.